React-Native Phone number Suggestions coming but not getting convert from example 9027-1334234 into 90271334234
Please anyone suggest this need to convert as well when number in suggestions coming with space
I have tried textContentType: telePhoneNumber, which gives suggestions but not able to convert into desired contact number . Note: For phone number suggestion you need to add your number into your contact card .
